# "Uninitialized Local Variable Used"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have a call to 2 functions which find the highest and lowest grade, respectively. they return "highestGrade" and "lowestGrade" but I am confused why the error appears when I compile. This is a lab assignment and most of the code was pre-written and I was tasked with filling in the missing code. The error occurs around lines 55 and 63, and the functions I am referring to are at the end of the code.

I am new to using arrays so I am assuming I may have some for of erroneous code inside the functions "findHighest" and "findLowest". For example, the program in "findHighest" will assume the first array it runs into is the highest grade and will compare the remaining arrays to it until it finds one that is higher. If it is, it will then assign that array to "highestGrade".

```
float findAverage(const GradeType, int);
int findHighest(const GradeType, int);
int findLowest(const GradeType, int);

int main()
{
    GradeType  grades;
    int  numberOfGrades;
    int pos;

    float avgOfGrades;
    int highestGrade;
    int lowestGrade;

    // Read in the values into the array
    pos = 0;
    cout << "Please input a grade from 1 to 100, (or -99 to stop)" << endl;
    cin >> grades[pos];
    int i = 1;

    while (grades[pos] != -99)
    {
        // read in more grades
        pos = i;
        cout << "Please input a grade from 1 to 100, (or -99 to stop)" << endl;
        cin >> grades[pos];
    }

    numberOfGrades = pos;  // Fill blank with appropriate identifier
                           // call to the function to find average
    findAverage(grades, numberOfGrades);
    avgOfGrades = findAverage(grades, numberOfGrades);
    cout << endl << "The average of all the grades is " << avgOfGrades << endl;

    //  Fill in the call to the function that calculates highest grade
    findHighest(grades, highestGrade);
    highestGrade = findHighest(grades, highestGrade);
    cout << endl << "The highest grade is " << highestGrade << endl;

    // Fill in the call to the function that calculates lowest grade
    findLowest(grades, lowestGrade);
    // Fill in code to write the lowest to the screen
    lowestGrade = findLowest(grades, lowestGrade);

    cout << endl << "The lowest grade is " << lowestGrade << endl;

    return 0;
}

float findAverage(const GradeType  array, int size)
{
    float sum = 0;   // holds the sum of all the numbers

    for (int pos = 0; pos < size; pos++)
        sum = sum + array[pos];

    return (sum / size);  //returns the average
}

int   findHighest(const GradeType array, int size)
{
    // Fill in the code for this function
    float highestGrade = array[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > highestGrade)
            highestGrade = array[i];
    }

    return highestGrade;
}

int   findLowest(const GradeType array, int size)
{
    // Fill in the code for this function
    float lowestGrade = array[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] < lowestGrade)
            lowestGrade = array[i];
    }

    return lowestGrade;
}
```

The program is unable to output the highest and lowest grade due to the error.

Comment: Since this is not the entire code. The errors due not appear exactly on lines 55 and 63. The errors occur with highestGrade and lowestGrade after the while loop in the main function.

Comment: The code does not compile.  When submitting code, it is helpful to provide sufficient code to allow a SO member to copy your code into their environment and compile without any changes.  Your code will not do that.  Could you please update the question?

Comment: That doesn't apply so much when the question is about a compiler error. That said, if the question is about `highestGrade`, why are there a couple dozen lines that have nothing to do with `highestGrade`? It's easier to find bugs early. Write a few lines of code, just enough to do one thing. Compile and debug. Do not proceed until there are no known problems. Rational: 1. It's easier to find bugs when they have less room to hide. 2. You are less likely to repeat the bug. 3. Bugs tend to interact with one another. Do not let them gang up on you.

Comment: You’re calling every function twice, ignoring the result of the first call.

Answer (score 1):

```
findLowest(grades, lowestGrade);
```

You are using `lowestGrade` before initializing it.

```
int lowestGrade;
```

should be

```
int lowestGrade = 0;  // or to anything that has meaning for your app.
```

And of course, as better C++, declare it just before you need it, not at the top of the function.

Same thing for the other variables.

All of this of course if the logic is correct. Why do you pass the lowest/higest grade as a size parameter in the functions?